# Sencha touch - Scrolling child also scrolls parent

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, dom-events, javascript-framework

In Sencha Touch I have parent panel along with child panel.

Both are scrollable, but when child is scrolled this triggers scroll event on parent panel also. It does not look good. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Changing the scrollable true to this in child panel solved my problem.

scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock: true
}

Just adding this so that it will be useful to someone else.